# what the wrong in this toggle function to checked all checkboxes

Tags: jquery, checkbox, click, toggle

I want when check one checkbox to check all other checkboxes

i used this code :

html:

```
<input type="checkbox" id="checkall" />

<input type="checkbox" name="rows[]" value="<?php echo $aut["aut_id"]; ?>" class="checkrow" />
<input type="checkbox" name="rows[]" value="<?php echo $aut["aut_id"]; ?>" class="checkrow" />
<input type="checkbox" name="rows[]" value="<?php echo $aut["aut_id"]; ?>" class="checkrow" />
<input type="checkbox" name="rows[]" value="<?php echo $aut["aut_id"]; ?>" class="checkrow" />
<input type="checkbox" name="rows[]" value="<?php echo $aut["aut_id"]; ?>" class="checkrow" />
```

jQuery:

```
        <script type="text/javascript">
            jQuery(document).ready(function(){                

                jQuery("#checkall").click(function () {
                    if(jQuery("#checkall").prop("checked") == true) {
                        jQuery(".checkrow").prop("checked", true);
                    }else{
                        jQuery(".checkrow").prop("checked", false);
                    }


                });
            });            
        </script>
```

Now, that's working fine but i want to ask are there another easiest or more direct way ??

specially i used this code but it didn't work and i want to know what the reason ??

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        jQuery(document).ready(function(){

            jQuery("#checkall").click(function() {  
                jQuery(".checkrow").toggle(function() {                        
                   jQuery(this).attr("checked", "checked");
                }, function() {                        
                   jQuery(this).removeAttr("checked");
                });            
           });
        });            
    </script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Take a look a this function:

```
function toggleChecked(status) {
   $("INPUT[type='checkbox']").each( function() {
   $(this).attr("checked",status);
})
```

This sets all checkboxes on your page to ***status***.

Answer (score 0):

Why not

```
jQuery(function($){                
    $("#checkall").click(function () {
        $(".checkrow").prop("checked", this.checked);
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

simplest way,

```
<input type="checkbox" name="checkall" id="checkall" onclick="$('input[type=checkbox][name^=rows]').attr('checked',this.checked)">
```

Answer (score 0):

```
jQuery(document).ready(function(){                
                jQuery("#checkall").click(function (e) {
                    jQuery(".checkrow").prop("checked", e.target.checked);
                });
});
```